# Vim/Neovim spellcheck not working with markdown files (but works with normal text files)

Tags: markdown, spell-checking, neovim, file-type

If I open or create a file with no extension (no `filetype`) or with a `.txt` extension (`filetype=text`), the spellcheck functionality **works as expected**. For example:

- Open/create a file: `$ nvim sample_TEXT_file.txt`
- Type some words in the file, such as: "Hello, the book is **oTn** the **tablw**."
- Activate the spell check functionality with the command `:set spell spelllang=en`
- The misspelled words will be highlighted as it should.

But when I open or create a markdown file (`.md` or `filetype=markdown`), my neovim's spell checking **doesn't work** at all. Repeating the example above:

- Open/create a file: `$ nvim sample_MARKDOWN_file.md` (`filetype=markdown`)
- Type some words in the file, such as: "Hello, the book is **oTn** the **tablw**."
- Activate the spell check functionality with the command `:set spell spelllang=en`
- Nothing happens. There is no highlight applied to any word.

On both examples (markdown or no-markdown filetypes), the spell check settings are the same and enabled (i.e. `:set spell spelllang=en`).

- `:set spell?` returns `spell`
- `:set spelllang?` returns `spelllang=en`

This seems like the same behavior as when I open a python file, for example. The spell check doesn't work either in this case.

How can I set up spell check for markdown files correctly?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @romainl I have edited the question now with a simple and reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `/usr/share/vim/runtime/fttplugin` specifically markdown.vim, probably your problem come from this file, it loads markdown settings every time you start editing a markdown file.

Comment: I opened the file `/usr/share/vim/runtime/fttplugin/markdown.vim` but I didn't identify a reason why this could be messing with the spell check feature of a markdown file.

Comment: Could also be an autocommand, possible!

Comment: if there is an `au` messing up with this config, which command should I look for? Which command is responsible for disabling the spell check feature for a specific filetype?

Comment: Try adding: `setlocal nospell` in your `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/markdown.vim` or  `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin`. Another option is adding a modeling see `:h modeline`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with neovim. In my case I could track down the issue to treesitter (`TSUninstall markdown` solves the issue).
Having spellsitter installed does not help.